# assign value of multiple variable to form an array variable in php

Tags: php, arrays, variables

```
$pn=$_POST['pn'];
$ln=$_POST['ln'];
$logn=$_POST['logn'];
$wellno=$_POST['wellno'];  
for($i=0; $i<$chkcount; $i++) 
 {
  $msg=echo$wellno[$i].':'.echo$ln[$i].'/'.echo$pn[$i].'-'.echo$logn[$i];
  echo "<br>";
 }
```

I want $msg as a variable to send a message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `echo` to concatenate variables. [`echo`](https://php.net/echo) returns nothing. Actually, you have a PHP Parse Error : *"syntax error, unexpected 'echo'"*.

```
$pn=$_POST['pn'];
$ln=$_POST['ln'];
$logn=$_POST['logn'];
$wellno=$_POST['wellno'];  
for($i=0; $i<$chkcount; $i++) 
{
    $msg = $wellno[$i].':'.$ln[$i].'/'.$pn[$i].'-'.$logn[$i];
    do_something_with($msg);
}
```

If you want to make an array, you could use `[]` operator to push the value into the array:

```
$msg=[];
for($i=0; $i<$chkcount; $i++) 
{
    $msg[] = $wellno[$i].':'.$ln[$i].'/'.$pn[$i].'-'.$logn[$i];
}
print_r($msg);
```